# React Router V6 IIS deployment Refresh not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v6 with my React application.
But I find that when I refresh the deployment app (with IIS), some of the paths could be loaded.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

The react method for routing.

##### Routes.js

```
const routes = (isLoggedIn) => [
  {
    path: '*',
    element: <EmptyLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <EmptyLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to={'/register'} /> },
      { path: '/register', element: <UserRegister /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to='/dashboard' /> : <EmptyLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '/auth/active/:code', element: <AccountActive /> },
      { path: '/auth/login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '', element: <Navigate to="/auth/login" /> },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    element: isLoggedIn ? <MainLayout /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />,
    children: [
      { path: '/dashboard/applications', element: <Applications /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/application/:id/edit', element: <ApplicationEdit /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/application/:id/view', element: <ApplicationView /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/users', element: <Users /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/user/:id', element: <UserDetail /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/shippers', element: <Shippers /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/shipper/:id', element: <ShipperDetail /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/staffs', element: <Staffs /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/groups', element: <Groups /> },
      { path: '/dashboard/group/:groupId/edit', element: <GroupEdit /> },
      { path: '/dashboard', element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/applications" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> }
    ],
  },
];
```

When I refresh at `/dashboard` it works okay, but if I refresh at `/dashboard/applications` then the page won't load. Same if I input URL directly.

##### App.js

I use routes in App.js

```
const { login } = authState;

  const routing = useRoutes(routes(login));

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ContextAProvider>
        <ContextBProvider>
          {routing}
        </ContextBProvider>
      </ContextAProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

##### index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter >
      <ContextCProvider>
        <App />
      </ContextCProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ and search for questions specifically dealing with redirecting page requests to your root index.html file so the app's deployment directory can handle rendering the app and letting the router handle navigating to the correct React page.

Answer (score 0):

Following [docs of React Router 6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) you don't need to use a parent part of link, so instead of

```
  {
    path: '/auth',
    element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to='/dashboard' /> : <EmptyLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '/auth/active/:code', element: <AccountActive /> },
      { path: '/auth/login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '', element: <Navigate to="/auth/login" /> },
    ],
  },
```

you have to use

```
  {
    path: '/auth',
    element: isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to='/dashboard' /> : <EmptyLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'active/:code', element: <AccountActive /> },
      { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: '', element: <Navigate to="/auth/login" /> },
    ],
  },
```